# How to strip out the suffix from url in regexp?

Tags: regex

I have two strings for url and I am building a regexp to take out the domain, project and repo from url.

The urls looks like this:

```
1. https://bitbucket.org/test/test-x.git

2. ssh://git@bitbucket.org/test/test-x
```

I have this regexp working:

```
r"(?:ssh|https):\/\/(?:(?:git@|)bitbucket.org)\/([^/]*)\/([^/]*)"
```

I am able to get `project` and `slug` group. Now, I also want to strip `.git` in regexp if it;s present in `slug` group, I tried with adding a non capturing group `(?:.git|)`, but no success.

How to omit `.git` with regexp if it is present in the string, what I am missing here?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```py
(?:ssh|https):\/\/(?:git@)?bitbucket\.org\/([^/]*)\/(.*?)(?:\.git|$)
```

[Regex demo.](https://regex101.com/r/33H7Ap/1)

---

`(?:ssh|https)` - match `ssh` or `https`

`(?:git@)?` - optionally match `git@`

`([^/]*)` - match first part of path

`(.*?)(?:\.git|$)` - match everything untill `.git` or end of line

Answer (score 2):

You can omit the outer non capture group `(?:` from your pattern because by itself it has no purpose in this context.

Note to escape the dot `\.` to match it literally.

If you want to match the slug without a dot you could omit it in the last character class `[^/.]*`

```
\b(?:ssh|https):\/\/(?:git@)?bitbucket\.org\/([^/]*)\/([^/.]*)
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PnLg4Z/1).

Or you could match any non whitespace character except for `/` `.` and only match the `.` when it is not directly followed by the word `git`

```
^(?:ssh|https):\/\/(?:git@)?bitbucket\.org\/([^/\s]*)\/([^/.\s]*(?:\.(?!git\b)[^/.\s]*)*)
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:ssh|https):\/\/` Match `ssh` or `https` then `://`
- `(?:git@)?bitbucket\.org\/`
- `([^/\s]*)\/` Capture **group 1**, match 1+ non whitespace chars other than `/` and then match the `/`
- `(` Capture **group 2**

  - `[^/.\s]*` Optionally match a non whitespace char except for `/` and `.`
  - `(?:` Non capture group (to repeat as a whole part)

    - `\.(?!git\b)` Match a dot if not directly followed by the word `git`
    - `[^/.\s]*` Optionally match a non whitespace char except for `/` and `.`
  - `)*` Close the non capture group and optionally repeat it
- `)` Close group 2

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rEtC3Y/1).